# python placeholder in eval method

Tags: python

I have an application in python where I'm evaluating snippets of code with the eval method (with some extra steps for safety) which will return a dict. The reason for this approach is that this way, my clients can configure some methods to their needs without needing to actually have access to the back-end code. However, I'm passing some helper functions with lots of variables to the environment, which need to be called several times. This makes the statement passed to eval look kind of cryptic. To be more specific, say I have a function:

```
def my_helper_function(some_string, some_boolean, some_int):
   # doing something here
   return {'foo': foo, 'bar': bar, 'baz': baz}
```

and a string that I want to evaluate to a dict with eval, which might look like this:

```
"{
   'foo': my_helper_function(some_string='x', some_boolean=True, some_int=12)['foo'],
   'bar': my_helper_function(some_string='x', some_boolean=True, some_int=12)['bar'],
   'baz': my_helper_function(some_string='x', some_boolean=True, some_int=12)['baz'],
   'oof': my_helper_function(some_string='x', some_boolean=False, some_int=12)['foo'],
   'rab': my_helper_function(some_string='y', some_boolean=True, some_int=11)['bar'],
   'zab': my_helper_function(some_string='x', some_boolean=False, some_int=12)['baz'],
}"
```

For a lot of lines, the parameters passed to my_helper_function will be the same, so it would be nice if I could have a placeholder, which would make above string look like:

```
"{
   'foo': placeholder['foo'],
   'bar': placeholder['bar'],
   'baz': placeholder['baz'],
   'oof': placeholder_2['foo'],
   'rab': my_helper_function(some_string='y', some_boolean=True, some_int=11)['bar'],
   'zab': placeholder_2['baz'],
}"
```

However, I can't simply define new variables in the string I want to eval, and I want to keep all options for personal configuration in there. Is there a way to define these placeholders in one expression so that eval can handle it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Will arguments be the same in one snippet or will they be the same in different snippets?

Comment: They will most of the time be different in different snippets, and using different helper functions. It's mostly about making every single snippet more easy to read.

Comment: They will also be different in different snippets where the same helper function is used? Had they most of the time been the same for the same helper function, then you could have used default values on the parameters.

Comment: Yes, that works. However, the point of this whole procedure is to make configuration options available for clients without access to the back-end. They'll likely get confused if the functions are always using default values, which are not visible in the snippets.

Comment: Do you think that it would work for the clients to add something like `'default' : { 'some_string': 'x', 'some_boolean': True, 'some_int': 42 }` into the dict? Or wrap the whole dict: `default(some_string='x', some_boolean=True, some_int=42, { ... })`?

Comment: Thanks, your comment gave me some ideas. I found a temporary solution (see below), and maybe I'll come up with something better later. If you want you can post an answer so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a comment I asked if it would work for the clients to add something like `'default' : { 'some_string': 'x', 'some_boolean': True, 'some_int': 42 }` into the dict or to wrap the whole dict: `default(some_string='x', some_boolean=True, some_int=42, { ... })`.

I also had the idea to make `my_helper_function` into an object that collects the arguments and the key and waits with the final evaluation so that you can pass it the defaults later:

```py
class Wrapper:
  def __init__(self, function):
    self.function = function

  def __call__(self, **kwargs):
    self.kwargs = kwargs

  def __getitem__(self, key):
    self.key = key

  def evaluate(self, defaults):
    return self.function(**(defaults | self.kwargs))


my_helper_function = Wrapper(_my_helper_function)

# Client uses
defaults = { 'some_string': 'x', 'some_boolean': True, 'some_int': 42 }
{
  'foo': my_helper_function(some_int=44)['foo']
}

# Then you do the real evaluation
# Assuming res = { 'foo': my_helper_function(some_int=44)['foo'] }
real_res = { key: value.evaluate(defaults) for key, value in res.items() }
```

Another idea is that the clients can enter something like

```py
res1 = my_helper_function(some_string='x', some_boolean=True, some_int=12)
{
   'foo': res1['foo'],
   'bar': res1['bar'],
   'baz': res1['baz'],
   'oof': my_helper_function(some_string='x', some_boolean=False, some_int=12)['foo'],
   'rab': my_helper_function(some_string='y', some_boolean=True, some_int=11)['bar'],
   'zab': my_helper_function(some_string='x', some_boolean=False, some_int=12)['baz'],
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For everyone wondering, I'm doing a little detour now, where I'm defining an additional string *defaults* which is also accessible by the client and gets evaluated first. Every helper function for which it makes sense can be added to the *defaults* string, which will also return a dict. To stick with my example above, I could have:

```
defaults_string = "{my_helper_function: {'some_string': 'x', 'some_boolean':True, 'some_int':12}}"
```

This dict is then used to update the context of the second eval. I.e. I'm using an additional function:

```
def _eval_context(defaults):
    new_context = {}
    for func in defaults.keys():
        func_defaults = func(**defaults[func])
        new_context.update({func.__name__: func_defaults})
    return new_context

context.update(_eval_context(eval(defaults_string, context)))
```

So with that, the string I want to evaluate as posted in my initial question would become:

```
"{
   'foo': my_helper_function['foo'],
   'bar': my_helper_function['bar'],
   'baz': my_helper_function['baz'],
   'oof': _my_helper_function(some_string='x', some_boolean=False, some_int=12)['foo'],
   'rab': _my_helper_function(some_string='y', some_boolean=True, some_int=11)['bar'],
   'zab': _my_helper_function(some_string='x', some_boolean=False, some_int=12)['baz'],
}"
```

That at least gives me one placeholder for defaults for each helper function. Note that for this to work I'm passing each helper function twice to the initial context, because one will be overridden by defaults.

```
context = {
'my_helper_function': my_helper_function,
'_my_helper_function': my_helper_function,
...
}
```

Still feels very clumsy to me, though.